# How to use Laravel Eloquent whereIn function on another table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

If two tables have relationship between them, I am using `with` function to get records considering value within condition from another table. For example:

`Table::where('column1', 'text1')->with('table2.column2', 'text2')`

My question is, how can I use `whereIn` function to set array of allowed values in `table2`?

`Table::where('column1', 'text1')->whereIn('table2.column2', ['text2', 'text3'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [Laravel's Constrained eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) to load your relationship.

**Example**

```php
Table::where('column1', 'text1')
    ->with(['table2' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('column2', ['text2', 'text3'])
    }])
    ->get();
```

If you don't need to load the relationship, then going with the `whereHas` solution provided by @bhavinjr is the best.

---

From the documentation :

> **Eager Loading Multiple Relationships**
>
> Sometimes you may need to eager load several different relationships in a single operation. To do so, just pass additional arguments to the with method:
>
> ```php
> $books = App\Book::with(['author', 'publisher'])->get();
> ```
>
> **Constraining Eager Loads**
>
> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify additional query conditions for the eager loading query. Here's an example:
>
> ```php
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>     $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
> }])->get();`
> ```

You can take a look at [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with) to have a deeper understanding of the `with` method.

Comment: Is there anywhere in laravel documentation written what are exactly the parameters of `with` method? Or if you could tell me, that would be great. First parameter is the name of another table, and what is the second parameter?

Comment: @niksrb You can read on documentation I shared links in my post. check both links

Comment: Wow, now this is exactly what I was looking for! Sorry @bhavinjr, but I gotta change my accepted answer to this one.

Comment: it's fine @niksrb we don't post for reputation we just want to help each other developers. that is the way we can improve our developing skills and resolve problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Table::where('column1', 'text1')
    ->whereHas('table2',function($q) {
        $q->whereIn('column2', ['text2','text3']);
    });
```

You must have to define relationship in model

This is the best practice

Refer: [Laravel Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Refer: [Query On Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can I use same logic if I want to use `whereNull` instead of `whereIn`? For example: `->whereNull('column2')`

Comment: yes you can use any of where  also you can use any methods which belong to `Table2 model`